# How can I use interface from a for loop

Tags: java, android, loops, interface, inner-classes

I have two `inner classes` named `CalculatorClass` and `UpdatePayment` in `MainActivity` class.
In `UpdatePayment` class there is a for loop and I have a `array` of `Buttons`.
I want to add listener to each button in loop. Those buttons will initialize the `CalculatorClass` and get value of calculations.

Demo code is:

```
public static class MainActivity{

    private interface UpdateEditText{
       void onCallback(String s);
    }
 
     private class CalculatorClass extends Dialog{
         UpdateEditText updateEditText;
         public CalculatorInterface(@NonNull Context context, UpdateEditText updateEditText) {
            super(context);
            this.updateEditText = updateEditText;
         }

           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                 setContentView(R.layout.calculator);
                 initialize();
           }
           initialize(){ 
              .......................
              s = "Some texts";
              updateEditText.onCallback(s);
           }
     }

     private class UpdatePayment extends Dialog{
         
             private Button[] button = new Button[100];
             private EditText[] editText = new EditText[100];

             public CalculatorInterface(@NonNull Context context) {
                super(context);
             }

             @Override
             protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                 setContentView(R.layout.update);
                 initialize();
             }
             initialize(){ 
                .......................
                for(int i = 0; i < MAXSize; i++){
                    button[i] = new Button(MainActivity.this);
                    editText[i] = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                    //add buttons to view to layout
                    button[i].setOnclickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    
                         public void onClick(View v) {
                             CalculatorClass calculator = new 
                                           CalculatorClass(MainActivity.this,
                                                    new UpdateEditText() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onCallback(String s) {
                                     editText[i - 1].setText(s);
                                 }
                            });
                            calculator.show();
                          }

                    );
                }
           }
     }
}
```

Problem is the line `editText[i].setText(s)` work for the last `editText` what ever button I click, i.e, any button I click, it fills the `editText[MaxSize -1]`

What should I do?
How can I perform this action for all `i`?
Please help me, I tried a lot searching in internet, still I didn't get any solution.

Comment: do you already initialized your button with `findViewById(R.id.button)` ?

Comment: Yes I did it in for loop but programmatically 
button[i] = new Button(MainActivity.this);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anonymous classes are very much treated like static variables in java.It's happenning because your i value after your activity is initialized is equal to 1 less than the length of the edit text array.
editText[indicies_of_button_clicke].setText(s)

How you will get the indicies of button clicked is by :
se the tag to button below this line  "editText[i] = new EditText(MainActivity.this);", like this :
button[i].setTag(i)

to retreive the index of your actual button clicked inside button clicklisteners,

```
  v.getTag()// this will give you an integer value which will be the indices of actual button clicked
           //use this value to set your edit text value.
```

Comment: Thanks, I just found my solution 1 min ago, after a whole night try.
pretty much as you suggested.
I just did as button[i].setId(i);
then v.getId();

By the way, thank you very much dear sir.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

After a whole night, I got answer, now I feel awwww, this was easy go!
I never came in this thought.

```
button[i].setId(i);
```

then call:

```
CalculatorClass calculator = new CalculatorClass(MainActivity.this, v.getId(),
                            new UpdateEditText() {
                                @Override
                                public void onUpdate(String s, int ID) {
                                    Log.i("test", ID + "");
                                    editText[ID].setText(s);
                                }
                            });
```

At the same time, @Rishabh Ritweek answered correctly.
Thanks to him.